# PHP Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' in Ubuntu

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I am trying to access my postgresql database from PHP using PDO:

```php
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$stm = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM books"); 
$books = $stm->fetchAll();
```

But I am getting this error:

```
GET /index.php - Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in index.php:28
```

So far I have tried:

1. `sudo apt install php-pgsql`
2. Uncomment `extension=pdo.so` in `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini`
3. `sudo service apache2 restart`
4. `sudo phpenmod pdo_pgsql`
5. Uncomment `extension=pdo_pgsql` in `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini`.
6. `sudo service postgresql restart`

Still, I am getting the same error. I am also getting this warning at the top:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Nov 25 2021 23:16:22) ( NTS )
```